# Format number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to format number in SQL Server. In example,

```
SET @B = '123456'
```

convert to

```
@B = '1234.56'
```

How to do that ?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just divide your number by 100 you will get result.

```
update yourtable set B=B/100
```

or it seeems like your B variable is varchar you can try this.

```
set @B=convert(varchar,cast(@B as decimal) / 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use some thing like this

```
select @B/1000.000;
```

or simple

```
select round(@B,2,1)
```

Comment: can you elaborate how `select round(@B,2,1)` gives `1234.56` and `set @B=@B/1000.000;` gives `123.456` not `1234.56`(with additional conversion required,otherwise it gives conversion error ).

Comment: @BibekGautam : Please check the above answer (marked as answer), This is down voted answer :)

Comment: so while giving answer you already know that your answer is not right?

Comment: Better to execute it in sql server, take @B as integer

Comment: again you are wrong if we take @B as integer how it can hold values like `1234.56`?

Comment: check now, i have modified